# Point grid in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, point, vector-grid, point-in-polygon

I'm working on a project that needs me to map out a point grid for drilling work.

The grid needs to fall within an already created polygon and be spaced 30x35meters. I was able to overlay a pointgrid with regular spacing, but it would overlay a big square in the layer. Moving and rotating it would make my qgis crash, and i still wasnt able to cut out the shape i needed.

I need the grid for archeological prospection work. I thought this should be an easy task, it seemed easier back when i used ArcGIS at least.

Is there no tool in QGIS3 to create a pointgrid within a polygon?

Comment: Ah thank you very much! Is there no other way to do so without having to apply coding? Since me and my colleges aren't familiar with coding.

Comment: I understand correctly that the QGIS tools Vector>Select>Regular points... or Vector>Select>Regular Mesh... doesn't suit you?

Comment: Sadly my qgis crashed before i got to take a screenshot, and i lost a lot of the progress. I hope to get to the same point again later today. But if i can find a solution before that i might be able to work more efficiently

Comment: How large is the polygon? How many (approximately) points do you expect to have in the final point grid? Thousands? Millions? Hundreds of millions?

Comment: I'm expecting to have around 200 points devided over 5 shapes

Comment: I use Vector Creation > Regular points... for archaeological sampling grids. No crashes from QGIS 3.x in UTM coordinate space.
If you specify a polygon in the Input Extent field it will place points only in that polygon.

Comment: Thank you @Nico, I'll try that in the future!